# Will resetting my unlocked phone to factory settings lock it again?

Tags: factory-reset, sim-unlocking, htc-dream

I have an unlocked G1 that is freaking out on me in various ways. If I "restore factory settings" am I going to wind up locking it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally unlocked phones are unlocked for good.  I wouldn't expect a factory reset to change it.  (See also: [Unlocked Galaxy i7500, Reset Will Remove it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14169/unlocked-galaxy-i7500-reset-will-remove-it))

It's not 100% certain, though.  For example, some Galaxy S users had their phones re-locked when updating from 2.1 to 2.2, which is a somewhat similar process to doing a factory reset.

You could always do a backup through ClockworkMod or something (and back it up to your computer first) in case it does get re-locked, so that you could restore it to the previous unlocked state.  That requires root, however.  (Root can sometimes be undone by a factory reset, but not if you have a custom ROM that came pre-rooted).

If you have the unlock code from when you originally unlocked it, that code should still work to unlock it again if it gets re-locked.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that, at least in this case, restoring the factory settings did not lock my phone.

Answer (score 3):

I have an HTC Sensation 4G that originally was purchased from T-mobile.  I unlocked it using the code provided by T-mobile (free) and used it on AT&T.  I just did a factory settings reset as instructed in the user manual and it still works fine and is still unlocked.