# Unlocked Galaxy i7500, Reset Will Remove it?

Tags: sim-unlocking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will resetting my unlocked phone to factory settings lock it again?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7145/will-resetting-my-unlocked-phone-to-factory-settings-lock-it-again)

I just purchased and unlocked a Samsung Galaxy i7500 using FastGSM's system. (It cost $20 and it's used up; I can't redo it.)

I know my phone has an option to "reset" it to the default/factory settings. **Will doing so re-lock my phone?** Is the lock hardware-level or OS/software-level? Can I upgrade the OS now that it's unlocked?

I noticed my app running a bit more slowly after unlocking, too... I just want to understand what level locking is on.

Comment: @MatthewRead possible. I would still like sn answer specific to my phone if possible though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the FastGSM page: "Congratulations! Your phone is permanently unlocked and can use it with different network SIM card. It will never relock again even if you do software update." ([source](http://www.fastgsm.com/en/page/how-to-unlock-samsung-i5700-spica-i5800-i5500-galaxy-3-5))

This means that even a factory reset won't relock the phone. I assume this is because Samsung phones use the /efs partition to store the IMEI and other network data, and the unlock modifies these files. The partition is not modified by updates/resets.

Comment: Okay, thanks for interpreting that for me. I had read that prior to unlocking, but I'm not clear on software vs. hardware as it pertains to locking.